# phonegap scanner app crashing on options button press

Tags: cordova, manifest, barcode-scanner

My app to scan barcodes is working ok but when i press the menu button while scanning it crashes.

The logcat is as follows

---

05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.mds.mytmt3/com.google.zxing.client.android.PreferencesActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(CaptureActivity.java:320)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:748)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-16 20:58:56.186: E/AndroidRuntime(8240):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

---

and my manifest file looks like this

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mds.mytmt3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:name=".MyPhoneGapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- ZXing activities -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" android:label="@string/share_name">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>           
    </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

i've searched everywhere as to how to declare android.preferencesactivity to the manifest but I'm getting nowhere.

Any help appreciated.